# What is the native resolution for the photos app wallpaper on a Lumia 920?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, photos

I'd like to set a static, custom wallpaper in the Photos app but I want to make sure the entire image will be viewable. What's the proper height and width, in pixels, for such an image?

Answer (score 2):

The Pictures Hub uses the [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) this is what developers are supposed to do to set the background in their apps --

> In this section, you will apply an image to the Panorama control. For
>   this topic, a sample image of samplePhoto.jpg is used. Use a properly
>   sized image in your app. Background images should be between **480 x 800
>   pixels and 1024 x 800** pixels (width x height) to ensure good
>   performance, minimal load time, and no scaling. If your image does not
>   have a height of 800 pixels, it will be stretched to that height
>   without preserving the aspect ratio.

According to the page, it applies to WP8 and WP7.1; however, I just created a new Panorama Project in Visual Studio, and checked the properties of the BackgroundImage.png in the default template and it is **1536x1280**.

I recommend you use these numbers to start and then answer your own question here when you find out the exact measurements.

Comment: I really wish they would have just mentioned 1536x1280 in the docs :)